# Retrieve the attribute list of records during querying process

Tags: django

I have model table so Tag and Article,

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    ...
class Article(models.Model):
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
```

I intent to retrieve the tags of a specified article and convert them to string:

1, Fetch the latest article:

```
In [26]: articles = Article.objects.all()
In [27]: len(articles)
Out[27]: 41
In [29]: a = articles[40]
In [30]: a 
Out[30]: <Article: Test new tags>
```

2, get it's tags queryset

```
In [32]: tags = a.tags.all()
In [32]: tags
Out[32]: <QuerySet [<Tag: python>, <Tag: django>, <Tag: git>, <Tag: javascript>]>
```

3, convert queryset to a stringset

```
In [36]: str_tags = ",".join([tag.name for tag in tags])
In [36]: str_tags   
Out[36]: 'python,django,git,javascript'
```

Could I get the str_tags directly by making an query?

Comment: instead of making two queries you can define a model like this since its M2M field ArticleTag = Article.tags.through,

Comment: Could you please transmit the comment to answer. @doubleo46

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`values_list('name', flat=True)`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#values-list):

```
tag_names = ",".join(a.tags.values_list('name', flat=True))
```

Aso to get last article just use [`last()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#last):

```
a = Article.objects.last()
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of making two queries you can define a something like this since its M2M field **ArticleTag = Article.tags.through**, 
then you can query like **tags =ArticleTag.objects.filter(article_id=id)**
then you can do **str_tags = ",".join([tag.name for tag in tags])**